# Access the list of valid values for an Enum field in a Mongoose.js Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The other day I saw a comment on the Web somewhere telling one how to access the list of values defined for an Enum field in a Mongoose.js Schema.  Sadly, I didn't commit that tidbit or its URL to memory and now I need it!

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var mongoose = require('./index')
, TempSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
salutation: {type: String, enum: ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.']}
});

var Temp = mongoose.model('Temp', TempSchema);

console.log(Temp.schema.path('salutation').enumValues);
var temp = new Temp();
console.log(temp.schema.path('salutation').enumValues);
```

*Source: https://gist.github.com/953059*

Comment: Why, yes! Yes, it is. Thank you!

Comment: I'm really surprised that enums are only mentioned about in the Mongoose validation documentation and not in the more generic "guide.html" that talks about schemata. Cheers for the heads up!

Comment: Is there an equivalent `enum` validation for non `String` types? For example,  on a `Number` field, which accepts only certain numbers.

Comment: @srt32 No, you'd have to check that yourself. Look [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this like I did, what worked for me in mongoose 5.x was:

```
Temp.schema.path('salutation').options.enums;
```