# How to get enum values from mongoose schema using virtual method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, enums, mongoose

I'm having difficulty getting enum values from my Mongoose schema using a virtual method on that same schema.

The property I'm trying to access in the schema is defined as follows:

```
, roles: {
    type: [{
        type: String
        , enum: ['user', 'admin']
    }]
    , default: ['user']
}
```

The following is my virtual method I'm using to grab the enum values:

```
// Returns an array of all possible role enum values
UserSchema.virtual('possibleRoles').get(function() {
    return this.schema.path('roles').caster.enumValues;
});
```

This works, however other examples I found online went about it in a different way. An example of this is here: [Access the list of valid values for an Enum field in a Mongoose.js Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640749/access-the-list-of-valid-values-for-an-enum-field-in-a-mongoose-js-schema)

Is my method for accessing enums on a property dirty or incorrect? Is there a cleaner way I could write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clean and easy way.

```
var possibleRoles = ['user', 'admin'];

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    roles: {
        type: [{type: String, enum: possibleRoles}],
        default: ['user']
    }
});

UserSchema.virtual('possibleRoles').get(function () {
    return possibleRoles;
});
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way. However, if I wanted to keep the array within the schema definition is my way of accessing it correct? Thanks.

Comment: you can access when type of roles is String and set enum value for it. then  in virtual method return this.schema.path('roles').enumValues;

Answer (score 0):

remove the caster part, i don't know why that is there:

        `return this.schema.path('roles').enumValues;`

that should work without any other issues